# Issue with link resolver if broker DB is inaccessible

Tags: broker, dynamic-linking, link-resolver

I am facing some fundamental issue with the Tridion "Link resolver" module; hopes I get some quick help from experts here. Please let me explain the problem statement.
Platform we are using: 
SDL Tridion - 2011 SP1
DLL- “6.1.0.348” version of “Tridion.ContentDelivery.dll”
Issue:
Link resolver functionality is working perfectly for my website but If in any case say the DB broker got inaccessible (via deadlock or other reason)  then “tridion:ComponentLink " control  throws an un-handled exception while resolving the link. Due to which the whole page got crash.
Below are the snippets of my published page

Query:
As this is Tridion default control hence we don’t have much control over it , what should we do to handle these type of exception?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's kind of expected behaviour.... Component linking works by looking up information about what pages components are used on and with what templates (for priority). This is done at the time of serving the link, as pages containing the required component may have been published or unpublished since the linking page was rendered. From the wording of your question I assume you are publishing your pages (as ASPX?) and binaries to a filesystem based storage and other data types to a database.

If your configuration is as mentioned above, then I suppose you could switch your storage configuration to use filesystem based storage for everything instead of the database... Then you wouldn't need a broker database at all. You'd need to measure the performance impact of making such a change and be aware that a database is mandatory if you want to publish taxonomies. This would also require a potentially significant amount of republishing!

As Nuno points out in the comments, Tridion's Content Delivery caching could also add value here (though only for those links to objects which have already been resolved and are thus in the cache). See the online documentation section about [Content Delivery caching](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-ADDADE3C-51F4-4DFA-978D-258923D8F375).

Comment: Also, proper use of Tridion caching should allow you to deal with these situations, you definitely don't want to query the DB for every link...

Comment: Wasn't 100% certain that Tridion caching would help but thinking more about it then of course it makes sense... Thanks Nuno.

Comment: Thanks Nuno Linhares, Can you please help me know how can i put this caching for this "tridion:ComponentLink" control?

Comment: CD Caching topic in SDL online docs: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-ADDADE3C-51F4-4DFA-978D-258923D8F375

Comment: Hey David thank you for replying, Yes i and publishing my page as (ASPX) only. Switching from DB to File system will not be feasible for me as it will be a big change and invites regression issues. So do you mean that its the expected behavior that if in any case Broker DB got in accessible this control will throw exception ?

Comment: Some caching-related links: https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/b/weblog/archive/2012/01/27/analyzing-the-tridion-object-cache and https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/b/weblog/archive/2009/05/05/what-is-the-sdl-tridion-object-cache